# Como devolver datos correctamente

Tags: python, python-3.x

Soy nuevo programando y me encuentro en el desafío de realizar un backup de archivos incremental.

Me he basado en el paradigma de programación orientado a objetos e intenté trabajar usando la buena práctica "DRY" (Don't repeat yourself) para evitar repetir mi código.

Les comento como tengo distribuido mi código:

**Archivo clases_main.py**

```
import glob
import os


class So:
    pass

class Folder:

    def set_directory(self, directory):
        self.directory = directory
        return directory


class File(Folder, So):

    def __init__(self, directory, extension):
        self.extension = self.set_extension(extension)
        self.directory = self.set_directory(directory)

    def set_extension(self, extension):
        self.extension = extension
        return  extension

    def buscar_archivos(self, directory, extension):
        os.chdir(directory)
        archivos = glob.glob(extension)
        for i in range(len(archivos)):
            filenames = archivos[i]
        return filenames
```

Por otro lado tengo un archivo adicional **backup_incremental.py**

```
from clases_main import File

directorio = 'D:/'
extension = '*.txt'

# Objeto de Instancia
search_archivos = File(directorio, extension)


archivos = search_archivos.buscar_archivos(directorio, extension)

for i in range(len(archivos)):
    print(archivos)
```

Me gustaría saber como puedo buscar los archivos txt de ese directorio y mostrar los nombres cuando ejecuto el archivo **backup_incremental.py**, cuando hago el for en este archivo, los nombres vienen repetidos por alguna razón, me gustaría también comenzar a aprender a mostrar datos en **json** si me pueden incluir algún consejo sobre esto también les agradeceré inmensamente.

**Edit:** He actualizado el código para no imprimir tanto

Saludos y gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Estas imprimiendo de mas en el método **buscar_archivos**:

```
import glob
import os

class File(object):

    def __init__(self, directory, extension):
        self.extension = extension
        self.directory = directory

    def buscar_archivos(self):
        os.chdir(self.directory)
        return glob.glob(self.extension)
```

Y en **backup_incremental.py**, usa **set** para eliminar duplicados:

```
from clases_main import File

directorio = 'D:/'
extension = '*.txt'

# Objeto de Instancia
search_archivos = File(directorio,extension)


archivos = search_archivos.buscar_archivos()

for archivo in set(archivos):
    print(archivo)
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, si le saco el print al archivo con clases ,  igualmente el for de backup_incremental.py devuelve todos los archivos de un solo nombre.

Answer (score 2):

Bueno, empecemos por el DRY.

En python no es necesario crear getters ni setters, por lo que puedes omitir los métodos que empiezan con set_, es decir:

```
...
class Directorio(object):
    def __init__(self, directory, extension):
        self.extension = extension
        self.directory = directory

    def archivos(self):
        directory = self.directory  # obtienes el directorio desde el __init__
        extension = self.extension  # obtienes la extension desde el __init__
        os.chdir(directory)
        archivos = glob.glob(extension)
        return archivos  # retorna la lista creada


# Luego creas la instancia
directorio = 'D:/'
extension = '*.txt'

search_archivos = Directorio(directorio, extension)
archivos = search_archivos.archivos()
for archivo in archivos:
    print(archivo)
...
```

El resultado te muestra dos veces en la pantalla porque estabas llamando dos veces a `print()`

Para mostrar en JSON, debes agregar un import y el siguiente metodo a tu clase:

```
...
def to_json(self):
    import json
    archivos = self.archivos()
    my_json = {}
    for archivo in archivos:
        _file = archivo.split('/')
        file = _file[len(_file) - 1]
        _file.pop()
        directory = '/'.join(_file)
        if directory in my_json:
            my_json[directory].append(file)
        else:
            if directory == '':
                directory = self.directory
            my_json[directory] = [file]
    return json.dumps(my_json)
...
```

Para recorrer el json, (como lo converstiste a string para pasarlo a json):

```
...
# Debes pasar el json a diccionario de python
my_json = json.loads(search_archivos.to_json())

for ruta in my_json:
   print("Archivos en '%(ruta)s': %(archivos)s" % {'ruta': ruta, 'archivos': ', '.join(my_json[ruta])})
...
```

Comment: Hola German gracias, me ayudas a entender esta parte de tu código?

class Directorio(Object):

El interprete me dice :

NameError: name 'Object' is not defined

Comment: Debería ser object , en minusculas

Comment: Veo que no brinda más ese error, pero el hecho de usar object quiere decir que el valor que retorna será de tipo objecto? O para que se usa concretamente?

Por otro lado para usar la función to_json como debería modificar este print que he añadido yo? Gracias

Comment: @secnot, ya lo corregí, gracias

Comment: Lo que lleva la clase en paréntesis son las clases de las que hereda, object es la clase raiz en python,  aunque no es obligatorio ponerla, está recomendado.

Comment: @HugoLesta , si, en python todo hereda de object, eso lo que quiere decir es que estas heredando de object, puedes directamente no ponerlo, pero incluso si en tu clase haces `CualquierClase.__mro__` veras que sale object

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación, para finalizar, podrías aconsejarme como usar este método que añadiste, to_json? debería remplazar el print que use por esto para obtener el dato en Json? Debo llamarlo de esta manera: to_json(archivo)? Gracias

Comment: @HugoLesta acabo de hacer una edición de la respuesta con tu inquietud

Comment: @GermanAlzateMartinez gracias, puedo ver que faltó una comilla simple de cerrar. el interprete me tira lo siguiente:

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

En que he fallado?

Comment: @HugoLesta, ya corregí, era un signo mal puesto

Comment: @GermanAlzateMartinez muchas gracias, ahora entiendo como mostrar Json, quiero consultarte una vez más porque el json devuelve un solo valor ruta : archivo cuando deberían ser 9 en mi caso , además la ruta aparece en blanco pero el archivo si aparece. 

Archivos en '': eula.1028.txt

Por que puede suceder esto?

Comment: @HugoLesta, acabo de hacer la corrección al método to_json(), sucede porque el directorio es el directorio raiz, entonces la ruta es efectivamente '', por otro lado, no te saldran 9 lineas, creo que saldrá una sola con todos los archivos separados por coma, pero si quieres mostrarlos de otra forma, puedes buscar como iterar sobre diccionarios en python